# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada

Tags: python, lista

Tengo muchos archivos .csv en una carpeta, y quiero listarlos a través de un código de python. Para eso uso el siguiente código:

```
path = "D:Users/ana.dias/MI COMPUTADOR PERSONAL S.A/Ana Dias Parra (Ana) - Ayuda EstudioClases/Ciencias Naturales/_archivos/temperatura/"

list_files = os.listdir(path)
```

y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: "D:Users/ana.dias/MI COMPUTADOR PERSONAL S.A/Ana Dias Parra (Ana) - Ayuda EstudioClases/Ciencias Naturales/_archivos/temperatura/"
```

Yo intenté cambiando el `/` por `\`, y también poniendo doble `/`: `//` pero no funcionó y ya no se qué más hacer.

Pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La ruta que has puesto de ejemplo no es una ruta valida. Tampoco es necesario que tengas que reemplazar nada manualmente. Ve directamente a la carpeta y copia la ruta y luego en su código guarda esa ruta en un string con una `r` al principio
así:

```
path= r"D:\ana.dias\Documents"
list_files = os.listdir(path)
```

**¿Por que la r al principio?**

Cuando pones la **r**, les dices a python que ignore los [caracter de escape](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp) y trate a todos los caracteres de forma literal.

Resulta que las rutas de los archivos y carpetas suelen contener caracteres de escape, como en tu caso `\temperatura` empieza con un `\t`. Cuando Python procesa tu string, le agrega el valor que corresponde el carácter de escape, en este caso \t corresponde a tabular. Entonces básicamente el valor real del string seria:

`emperatura`
en vez de `\temperatura`

Comment: Mil gracias! Pude solucionarlo con tu sugerencia

Comment: Un gusto. Por si te preguntabas el por qué de la r al principio, he editado la respuesta y le agregue una pequeña explicación.

Answer (score 0):

```
aunch python

exit code: 3

stderr:
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.

Launch unsuccessful. Exiting.
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
buenas tardes amigos una ayuda me sle esto de arriba cunado ya lo arregle envio el arreglo 
@echo off

set PYTHON="C:\Users\Dpa_i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
set GIT=
set VENV_DIR=
set COMMANDLINE_ARGS=

call webui.bat
```

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/389047)